# Reading every single line from txt file C#

Tags: c#, streamreader, readline

i want to read every single line form txt file. Instead of every line i get every second line. The question is why and how can i do something about it.
list.txt:
60001
60002
60003
60004
..every number in single line and so on 100 lines

```
        StreamReader podz = new StreamReader(@"D:\list.txt");

        string pd="";
        int count=0;

        while ((pd = podz.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n number: {0}", podz.ReadLine());
            count++;

        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n c {0}", count);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: use `pd` rather than readline into pd, then readline.  Your code currently readlines into pd, diregards it, and readlines - 2 readlines per iteration of the loop

Comment: Why not just use `File.ReadAllLines(string path)`? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you can just do `foreach (string line in lines)` and this way you won't even need `int count` because you have `lines.Count`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're reading two lines per loop iteration:

```
while ((pd = podz.ReadLine()) != null) // here
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n number: {0}", podz.ReadLine()); // and here
    count++;
}
```

Instead, just read the line in the first place and use the `pd` variable in which you store the line in the second place:

```
while ((pd = podz.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n number: {0}", pd);
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *File* instead of *Streams* and *Readers*:

```
   var lines = File
     .ReadLines(@"D:\list.txt");

   int count = 0;

   foreach (var line in lines) {
     Console.WriteLine("\n number: {0}", line);
     count++;
   }

   Console.WriteLine("\n c {0}", count);
   Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Maybe this is dumb question, but what part of this is LINQ? You don't need LINQ for `File.ReadLines`, do you? Also I guess you know this but no point in retaining `int count` and incrementing it in your loop as you can just use `lines.Length`

Comment: @sab669: you're quite right, it's not *Linq* but at most `IEnumerable<String>`; It will no point to increment `count` within loop in case of `ReadAllLines` (please, notice `All`), but `ReadLines` returns just `IEnumerable<String>`. If the file is of unknown size, `ReadLines` is a safier choice then `ReadAllLines`

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some problems:

- You are reading the line incorrectly (calling `ReadLine` twice per each iteration)
- You are not closing the `Stream`
- If the file is in use by another process (i.e. a process writing to the file) you may get some errors

The `StreamReader` class is useful when the size of the file is very large, and in case you are dealing with a small file you can simply call `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("FileName")`.

In case the size of the file is large, follow this approach

```
public static List<String> ReadAllLines(String fileName)
{
    using(System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read))
    {
        using(System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fs))
        {
            List<String> lines = new List<String>();
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                lines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }
            return lines;
        }
    }
```

Comment: change this to `IEnumerable<string>` and instead of `lines.Add` use `yield return sr.ReadLine();`

Comment: And you can just pass the filename to the `StreamReader` instead of opening the `FileStream` manually

Comment: @MatthewWhited: That results in a deferred execution, I think the user may have problem with that. The `FileStream` allows the file to be still accessible even if it is in use by another process.

Comment: `new StreamReader(path : string)` create a `FileStream` with the same parameters.  so yes, you will hold the file open but you will also use less memory and only read as much of the file as you want if you early exit.

Comment: `Stream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.SequentialScan, Path.GetFileName(path), false, false, checkHost);` in particular.